# boost scoped_lock vs plain lock/unlock

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, mutex

I'm going to use `boost::mutex` from `boost/thread/mutex.hpp`.
There are several ways to lock/unlock mutex: with `scoped_lock`, `unique_lock`, `lock_guard`, mutex's member functions `::lock()` and `::unlock()` and nonmember functions `lock()` and `unlock()`.

I noticed, that `boost::scoped_mutex` is one of the most popular ways of using mutex. Why is it preferable to member functions `::lock()` and `::unlock()`?

Particularly, why should I use

```
{
  boost::scoped_lock lock(mutex)
  // ...
  // read/output sharing memory.
  // ...
}
```

rather than

```
mutex.lock()
// ...
// read/output sharing memory.
// ...
mutex.unlock()
```

is `scoped_lock` better just because of some style-coding point of view or is `::lock()/::unlock()` not "thread safe enough"?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

> Why is it preferable to member functions ::lock() and ::unlock()?

For the same reason why the [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) became popular in general (this is just one of its countless instances): because you can be sure you don' leave the current scope without unlocking the mutex.

Notice, that this is not just about *forgetting* to call `unlock()`: an exception may occur while your mutex is locked, and your call to `unlock()` may never be reached, even though you do not have any `return` statement between your call to `lock()` and your call to `unlock()`.

```
m.lock() // m is a mutex
// ...
foo(); // If this throws, your mutex won't get unlocked
// ...
m.unlock()
```

In this case, the destructor of your `scoped_lock` guard will be invoked during stack unwinding, making sure the associated mutex *always* gets released.

```
{
    boost::scoped_lock lock(m); // m is a mutex
    // ...
    foo(); // If this throws, your RAII wrapper will unlock the mutex
    // ...
}
```

Moreover, in many situations this will improve your code's readability, in that you won't have to add a call to `unlock()` before every `return` statement.

Answer (score 9):

you can use

`std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);`

if don't want to use boost library.