# Can I lock multiple variables simultaneously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm asking a question about multithreading.

Say I have two global vectors,

```
std::vector<MyClass1*> vec1
```

and

```
std::vector<MyClass2*> vec2.
```

In addition, I have a total number of 4 threads which have access to ***vec1*** and ***vec2***. Can I write code as follows ?

```
void thread_func()
// this is the function that will be executed by a thread
{
    MyClass1* myObj1 = someFunction1(); 
    MyClass2* myObj2 = someFunction2();

    // I want to push back vec1, then push back vec2 in an atomic way
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    vec1.push_back(myObj1);
    vec2.push_back(myObj2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
}

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
}
```

What I want to do is that, I want to perform push_back on ***vec1*** followed by push_back on ***vec2***.

I'm a newbie and I have a feeling that one can only lock on one variable with a mutex. In other words, one can only put either ***vec1.push_back(myObj1)*** or ***vec2.push_back(myObj2)*** in between ***pthread_mutex_lock(mutex)*** and ***pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex)***.

I don't know if my code above is correct or not. Can someone correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Side note: You might consider std::thread (C++11) and pass the vectors as reference (via std::ref) to the thread functions (to avoid globals).

Answer (score 5):

Your code is correct. The mutex is the thing being locked, not the variable(s). You lock the mutex to protect a piece of code from being executed by more than one thread, most commonly this is to protect data but in general it's really guarding a section of code.

Comment: Are you talking about critical section ? Can you point me to some good tutorials ?

Comment: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes talkes about mutexes, and says: Very often the action performed by a thread owning a mutex is the updating of global variables. This is a safe way to ensure that when several threads update the same variable, the final value is the same as what it would be if only one thread performed the update. The variables being updated belong to a "critical section".

Comment: If I just may pinpoint a potential issue:  `push_back()` might raise an exception.  In this case you'd loose the control over the mutex which might remain blocked for all the threads. Execute the critical secton i a try catch block.  Or use `std::threads` and `std::lock_guard()` instead...

Comment: Good point @Christophe, always use a RAII for mutex and as std::lock_guard is there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write like this but there are a few techniques you should definitely consider:

1. **Scoped lock** pattern for exception-safety and better robustness in general.
   This is nicely explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15179582/950708)
2. **Avoid globals** to let optimizer work smarter for you. Try to group data into logical classes and implement locking inside it's methods. Smaller scope of variables also gives you better extensibility.