# What happens when more than one thread tries to update form controls using Invoke at the same time in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

What happens when more than one thread tries to call a form method using Invoke which updates form controls at the same time in Winforms?

```
        static thCount = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(start);           
            System.Threading.Thread t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(start);
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
        }    
        private void start()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(guiUpdate));
        }    
        private void guiUpdate()
        {
            this.label1.Text = "Updated.." + (thCount++);
            this.label1.Update();            
        }    
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
        }
```

Comment: The best answer should be "the program crashes".

Comment: Why would it crash?  I'm not disputing that it may, 'cos I haven't tried it, but would the Invokes not simply be serialized?  'Invoke' is, essentially, SendMessage() API?

Answer (score 2):

Try it out! :) You'll find that neither of them can update the UI from a background thread, instead they need to use `Control.BeginInvoke` to invoke work on the UI thread, in which case they will execute in the order that they call `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: IIRC, some winforms versions will actually let you do it. Thinking <=2.0 maybe? (Of course, not that you *should* do it!)

Comment: Yup, looks like you're right - the WinForms that shipped in 2003 (I think that would be <2.0?) didn't have this restriction. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx for more info, well spotted! (That said, that's ancient history these days...)

Answer (score 1):

Either of the thread will not be able to update the GUI.

You might get cross thread exception if you do not check 'InvokeRequired'.

if you still want these threads to access the same method, you can use **Mutual Exclusion** concept.

You can find more on Mutual Exclusion [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989451/mutex-example-tutorial) on stack overflow also explain Mutual Exclusion in detail.

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke` blocks until the thread has finished executing the update method.

However, this is actually only a message to the GUI thread to do this and it waits until it is done. Since the GUI thread can only execute one method at a time there is no real simultaneous execution. Nothing bad happens, but the behaviour may depend on the sequence of execution.

The sequence of execution, however, depends on which thread ever finished some guaranteed atomic (lock) operation.

Comment: This is what I would have expected, but other answers say otherwise?

Comment: It appears question had been edited such that previous answers don't seem to match anymore.