# Thread synchronization using one to one model

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

How is one to one synchronization implemented in multi threading? How are the mutexes or semaphores used in the model? Some examples would be nice.

Comment: Asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989451/mutex-example-tutorial.  Follow the numerous links in this question, and you'll be on your way

Comment: @Bukes It's helpful, but right now I am only well aware of barrier synchronization. I need to know how is one to one synchronization model implemented in multi threading.