# Mutex lock on separate classes

Tags: c++, multithreading

What is the correct use of a Mutex? How do I know what it is protecting? Does it stop all threads from running for the locked period?

For example I have a singleton that contains a list of objects.

```
class Foo
{
    // Pretend this is a singleton.
    std::list<Object>* GetObjects() { return &objects; }
    void Reset() { for ( auto iter = objects.begin(); iter != objects.end(); ++iter ) { delete *iter; } }
    std::list<Object> objects;
};
```

In a separate class I have a update method. This is run in a seperate thread.

```
class Bar
{
    void Update()
    {
        std::list<Object>* objects Foo.GetObjects(); 
        for(auto iter = objects.begin(); iter != objects .end(); ++iter )
            iter->SetTransform(50,50,50);
    }
};
```

My Problem is that I want to call Reset() on Foo, and delete all the objects. But my Bar class is updating all these objects. So if it is in the middle of a update method it may be trying to modify a object that has been deleted.

How do I prevent this?

Can I just create a Mutex in reset function and lock it before deleting and unlock it after? Something like this:

```
 void Reset()
 {
     Mutex mutex; mutex.Lock()
     for ( auto iter = objects.begin(); iter != objects.end(); ++iter )
         delete *iter;
     mutex.Unlock();
}
```

Does this let the other class know these resources are locked? I am not sure how the mutex knows what information to protect. How does it know that it needs to lock the list in the singleton class.

Btw this is all pseudo code so there is syntax errors and missing information.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this [Mutex example / tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989451/mutex-example-tutorial?rq=1) =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct use of a Mutex?

To synchronize access to a shared resource.

> How do I know what it is protecting?

By reading the code.  Whatever is accessed when the lock is acquired is what is being protected.

> Does it stop all threads from running for the locked period?

No.  Only people who wait on the Mutex are "stopped".  A thread will wait when you call `Lock()` if some other thread already has the lock.  It will wait until whoever has the lock calls `Unlock()`.  If nobody has the lock then the thread calling `Lock()` acquires it and does not wait.  Multiple threads may be waiting if you have a lock and who gets it when it is unlocked is not necessarily defined.  Refer to the documentation for your particular framework.

> How do I prevent this?  Can I just create a Mutex in reset function and lock it before deleting and unlock it after?

You can prevent simultaneous access to a shared resource by multiple threads if you acquire and release the lock around access to that shared resource.  So, yes, you can lock and unlock around your reset code, but you need to do it in all the places that access your shared resource.

In this case `objects` is your shared resource.  If you acquire the lock in the place you delete the contents of `objects`, you must also acquire the lock in places where you're using it.  Since you give out a reference via `GetObjects()` you would also need to have callers of that realize access needs to be synchronized via this mutex.

An alternative scheme would be to get rid of `GetObjects()` and have other methods, for example `Object *get(int index)`, that get / set / manipulate the data inside the lock and never actually give out a raw reference to `objects`.

> Does this let the other class know these resources are locked? I am not sure how the mutex knows what information to protect.

No.  The Mutex doesn't know anything.  You must impose the proper semantics on the code, either by documenting it for callers or thunking all access to the shared resource through an object that knows to acquire the Mutex.

Comment: Does it have to be the same Mutex? Or can it be a seperate mutex for reset() and update().

Comment: It has to be the same one.  The problem you have now is you acquire the lock to do the reset operation, but nobody else waits for the lock to be released.  By locking the Mutex before accessing objects if the reset operation is running the other thread will have to wait for the reset to finish before Lock() returns and execution continues on the first thread.  If you create two different Mutexs then you essentially have the same problem, because mutexA.Lock() will not wait if someone has locked mutexB.

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms, a mutex is a **locking** mechanism.

say, you have a resource, in your case `list<object> objects;`
Now , If multiple threads end up operating on this list concurrently, then, the outcome of these operations could be unexpected.

so, basically mutex gives us a mechanism that ensures that only one thread operated on the protected resource one at a time.

*Implementation:*

In Linux kernel, a thread is modeled by a `task_struct` object.And mutex implementation is as follows:

```
struct mutex {
  /* 1: unlocked, 0: locked, negative: locked, possible waiters */
  atomic_t                count;
  spinlock_t              wait_lock;
  struct list_head        wait_list;
 #if defined(CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES) || defined(CONFIG_MUTEX_SPIN_ON_OWNER)
  struct task_struct      *owner;
 #endif
}
```

So, first thread to try to lock mutex becomes the `owner` and everyone else is added to `wait_list` of that mutex.

Once the owner releases it, the next task from the `wait_list` gets the next chance.

Note that

> in case of mutex, whoever locks it has to unlock it,

else everyone else will be locked forever, also known as *dreadlock*.