# threading.h:10:24: fatal error installation error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, bioinformatics

Fairly unknowledgable linux (ubuntu 14.04) user here. I'm trying to install a bioinformatics program called Bowtie2 - I get this error and not sure where it's coming from. They did quote this on their website which might have something to do with it, but didn't mention it as a dependency.

> TBB is now the default threading library. We consistently found TBB to
>   give superior thread scaling. It is widely available and widely
>   installed. That said, we are also preserving a "legacy" version of
>   Bowtie that, like previous releases, does not use TBB. To compile
>   Bowtie source in legacy mode use NO_TBB=1. To use legacy binaries,
>   download the appropriate binary archive with "legacy" in the name.

```
sam@SumnerLab-Computer:~/Program_Files/bowtie-1.2$ make
g++ -w -O3 -m64 -DCOMPILER_OPTIONS="\"-O3 -m64  -Wl,--hash-style=both -DWITH_TBB -DPOPCNT_CAPABILITY -DNO_SPINLOCK -DWITH_QUEUELOCK=1  \""  -Wl,--hash-style=both -DWITH_TBB -DPOPCNT_CAPABILITY -DNO_SPINLOCK -DWITH_QUEUELOCK=1    \
    -fno-strict-aliasing -DBOWTIE_VERSION="\"`cat VERSION`\"" -DBUILD_HOST="\"`hostname`\"" -DBUILD_TIME="\"`date`\"" -DCOMPILER_VERSION="\"`g++ -w -v 2>&1 | tail -1`\"" -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE  -DPREFETCH_LOCALITY=2 -DBOWTIE_MM -DBOWTIE_SHARED_MEM -DNDEBUG -Wall \
    -I SeqAn-1.1 -I third_party -I third_party \
    -o bowtie-build-s ebwt_build.cpp \
    ccnt_lut.cpp ref_read.cpp alphabet.cpp shmem.cpp edit.cpp ebwt.cpp  bowtie_build_main.cpp \
    -lpthread -ltbb -ltbbmalloc_proxy 
In file included from pat.h:17:0,
                 from sequence_io.h:12,
                 from multikey_qsort.h:8,
                 from diff_sample.h:8,
                 from blockwise_sa.h:13,
                 from ebwt.h:27,
                 from ebwt_build.cpp:11:
threading.h:10:24: fatal error: tbb/mutex.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:259: recipe for target 'bowtie-build-s' failed
make: *** [bowtie-build-s] Error 1
```

Any ideas what the issue might be?

thanks

Comment: Check in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5154174/2681245)

Comment: I don't know from mutexs, but if you're you want bowtie2, you shouldn't be compiling bowtie-1.2. The latest version is [2.3](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/index.shtml). For the unknowledgable, I would recommend downloading the precompiled binary, or clicking on the bioconda link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to install the package TBB development package, e.g. `libtbb-dev`.

On Ubuntu, run `sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev`

Answer (score 0):

​sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev

​make