# Could someone explain how pointers an references work with pthreads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I'm trying to do a simple program that prints values using threads to test POSIX pthreads because I haven't used them before. The thing is that I know in a general way what's happening and how treads work, but I'm completely clueless about them working with pointers and references.

This is my program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex m;

void* thread1(void* n)
{   m.lock();
    
    int* number = static_cast<int*>(n);

    (*number)++;

    std::cout << "THREAD 1: " << *number << std::endl;

    sleep(1);

    m.unlock();

    return number;
}

void* thread2(void* n)
{   m.lock();
    
    int* number = static_cast<int*>(n);

    (*number)++;
    
    sleep(1);

    std::cout << "THREAD 2: " << *number << std::endl;

    m.unlock();

    return number;
}


int main(void)
{   pthread_t t1, t2;
    int i = 0;
    int* n;

    while (i < 10)
    {   pthread_create(&t1, nullptr, thread1, &i);
        pthread_create(&t2, nullptr, thread2, &i);

        pthread_join(t2, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&n));
        pthread_join(t1, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&n));

        //i = *n;
    }
}
```

The output should be the following:

```
THREAD 1: 1
THREAD 2: 2
THREAD 1: 3
THREAD 2: 4
THREAD 1: 5
THREAD 2: 6
```

But instead it's this one:

```
THREAD 1: 2050832128
THREAD 2: 1
THREAD 1: 2050832128
THREAD 2: 2
THREAD 1: 2050832128
THREAD 2: 3
(THREAD 1 repeats a random number for ever
but THREAD 2 does what it should.)
```

I know it has to do with the way I'm managing my variables, but don't know how to fix it.

**EDIT 1**: Added some Mutex functionalities and commented `i = *n` to see how the numbers came out.

**EDIT 2**: Changed `*number++` to `(*number)++` in `void* thread1(void*)` and now everything works properly.

All the information about Mutex you need to understand this post is in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989451/mutex-example-tutorial).

Comment: When you do `int* n;`, what does `n` point to?

Comment: Initially nowhere. That variable is where the return value of the functions will be stored with 'pthread_join'.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable regarding pthread but you are casting a pointer with one level of indirection (`int*`) to a pointer with two levels of indirection (`void**`) which is a huge red flag to me. Edit : My guess would be that `reinterpret_cast<void**>(n)` should just be `&n`.

Comment: @HTNW Nope, same result, but thanks ^^

Comment: Your threads are both accessing `i` for write without synchronization. Your code has undefined behavior, even if those sleeps make it seem like it has the expected behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, it makes sense, but how should I access the value pointed by n?

Comment: You have two problems with the code, one more subtle than another. The not-so-subtle one is that you pass a pointer to the pointer to the integer to thread, but treat it as if it was a pointer to integer (mismatch in levels of indirection). The subtle issue is un-synscronized access to non-atomic variables from two different threads.

Comment: @Simeón You need to introduce synchronization, usually with a `mutex` object, to make sure the threads aren't using the variable at the same time. Multithreading is one of the most difficult things to get right in C++ and it cannot be adequately explained in a Q/A post, much less a comment. You should find a reputable book on the subject to get started.

Comment: On top of everything else, `*number++;` *certainly* isn't doing what you think. That doesn't increment the value pointed-to, it increments the pointer after retrieving the current value, used in a dereference operation and the result of which never actually used for *anything*.

Comment: fwiw, with `std::thread` you can have have same trouble but in contrast to bare pthreads you dont have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate issue lies in these lines:

```
pthread_join(t2, reinterpret_cast<void**>(n));
pthread_join(t1, reinterpret_cast<void**>(n));
```

The pthreads library will **dereference** the pointer you pass to `pthread_join` and modify the pointed-to pointer to point to the thread function's return value.  `n` doesn't point to a pointer (or anything, for that matter) though, and so things go off the rails.

Instead of passing `n` to `pthread_join`, you need to pass a a pointer to `n`:

```
pthread_join(t2, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&n));
pthread_join(t1, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&n));
                                       // ^---- Note the extra &
```

---

After fixing that issue you'll find a couple of others.  As noted in the comments to the OP, `*number++` increments the pointer `number`, dereferences the (invalid) pointer and then immediately discards the result.  It does not increment the value pointed to by `number` as you likely intend.  For that you want `(*number)++`.

Your code also has a data race since there's no synchronization between your two threads and they both try to modify `i`.  You'll need some sort of synchronization (i.e. a mutex or atomic variable) to make your program's behavior well-defined.

---

Note also that pthreads is a C interface.  You'll find it doesn't play well with lots of C++ features.  You'll likely want to use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) for most C++ applications.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `&n` is an address of `n`, which points to an int. Everything is OK. Using a pointer with the name `n` is a bad idea, as it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Data race is evident, but it can be "fooled" by using different time intervals in each `sleep`. Not kosher, incorrect, but may make OP happy for a while. Of course a program with a race condition is incorrect, so the next thing OP should do is to learn about data races and how to deal with them in pthreads.